# Socket blocking in wrong order

Tags: python, java, sockets, server, tcp

I'm using a python client to connect to a Java server. The client is supposed to send a message to the server, the server processes it and sends an answer. When I don't wait for an answer it works. 
The problem is, although my socket.send comes before the socket.recv, the recv method is blocking before something is sent. How do I get the socket to send the text before it wants to receive?
I know the server is working because if I do the client in Java it works.

 Python code:

```
text = from_microphone()
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.send(bytes(text, 'utf-8'))
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
speak(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Java server:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6969);
        while(true){
            Socket client = server.accept();
            String input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())).readLine().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
            /*
            * processing
            */
            String answer = "test";
            new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true).println(answer);
            client.close();
        }
```

Comment: What matters is not the Language (Python of Java) but exactly what is send and how. You have not shown the working Java client, so I cannot know exactly what is the difference with the Python version. Wild guesses: one contains a *terminating* character like a newline or a null while the other does not; or it uses (explicitely or implicitely) a *shutdown* to signal the server that the input data is finished.

Comment: Try adding an explicit new line character ('\n') at the end of the message in python client.

Comment: @SergeBallesta thanks, the newline character was missing, in the java client I used "println" which automatically adds it.